# TypeError : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to do modelling BSTS (Bayesian Structural Time Series) with Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) method using *stan especially pystan and also python* to get the graphical result ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9soju.png)). I finished modelling using *pystan* for plot the graphic estimated using BSTS or dotted line Baseline ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9soju.png)), but I have trouble in modelling equations in *python* ([picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCM8.png)) to get the observation graphic or Measurement data ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9soju.png)).

picture 1:

[image: picture 1]

picture 2:

[image: picture 2]

This is [reference](https://www.takayabe.net/post/pystan-bsts) that I used in this case.

Note: subscript t = 1,2,3,..,104 and subscript i = 0,1,2,...,7

```py
#Generate dummy data for BSTS
SEED = 1234
NUM_SAMPLES_t = 250
NUM_SAMPLES_i = 7

def generate_data_dummy_bsts():
  #x = 2*np.random.normal(250, 1, 150) - np.random.normal(250,1,150)
  #xt = 2*np.array(range([NUM_SAMPLES_t - 1])) - np.array(range([NUM_SAMPLES_t - 2]))
  #x[1] = -xt[-1] + np.random.normal(250, 1, 150)
  A = 10
  B = 10
  KD = 10
  xt_array = np.array(range(NUM_SAMPLES_t))
  qt_array = np.array(range(NUM_SAMPLES_t))
  qi_array = np.array(range(NUM_SAMPLES_i))

  for t in range(xt_array):
    x[t] = 2*x[t-1] - x[t-2] + np.random.normal(250, 1,150)
    xt = x[t]
  for t in range(qt_array):
    if (NUM_SAMPLES_t < 65):
      for i in range(qi_array):
        q[i] = 0
    else :
      for i in range(qi_array):
        tau[i] = A*np.log(c[i]) + B + np.random.normal(250,1,150)
        Q[i] = a*c[i] / KD + c[i]
        q[i] = (Q[i] - Q[i-1])(1 - np.exp(-t - 65 / tau[i]))
 
    qt = np.sum(q)
  #observation
  y = xt + qt + np.random.normal(250, 1, 150)
```

When i try to plot this equation in def function to get the graphical result

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
ax.plot(generate_data_dummy_bsts())
plt.show()
```

I have error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-dc3e483a266e> in <module>()
      1 fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
----> 2 ax.plot(generate_data_dummy_bsts())
      3 plt.show()

<ipython-input-17-d188897a3bbb> in generate_data_dummy_bsts()
     11   qi_array = np.array(range(NUM_SAMPLES_i))
     12 
---> 13   for t in range(xt_array):
     14     x[t] = 2*x[t-1] - x[t-2] + np.random.normal(250, 1,150)
     15     xt = x[t]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: The range argument cannot be a list, so it must be replaced by this one.`for t in xt_array:`

Comment: @r-beginners thank you for your answered, but if i replaced of code from your suggest, i have error message too. this is error message

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dc3e483a266e> in <module>()
      1 fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
----> 2 ax.plot(generate_data_dummy_bsts())
      3 plt.show()`

Comment: `<ipython-input-5-8f056e3e00f1> in generate_data_dummy_bsts()
     12 
     13   for t in xt_array:
---> 14     x[t] = 2*x[t-1] - x[t-2] + np.random.normal(250, 1,150)
     15     xt = x[t]
     16   for t in qt_array:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: I guess you want ``for t in range(len(xt_array)):`` instead of ``for t in range(xt_array):``

Comment: thankyou @Karina, but i am still got error message same like previously

Comment: what is ``x[t]`` under ``for t in range(xt_array):``? It is undefined. For future reference, please use the standard 4 spaces for indentation. It could be very discouraging for other people (at least for me) to test out you code since the indentations don't match well.

Comment: a lot of variables are not defined. What is ``x``, ``q``, ``tau``, ``c``, ``Q``? they are not defined anywhere.